# How to remove this filter?

Tags: filters

I can't remove a filter that added by media-tags plugin. it was originally added this way:

```
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'mediatags_show_fields_to_edit', 11, 2 );
```

I tried to remove it this way:

```
remove_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit','mediatags_show_fields_to_edit', 11, 2 );
```

Where I did wrongly? How can I remove this filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the call sequence. Are you sure that the `remove_filter` is called after the `add_filter` and before the `attachment_fields_to_edit` filter is invoked? Add few trace statements and verify.

Comment: the original filter was added inside a function that hooked up with 'admin_init'. My remove_filter is hooked up with my plugin's init. I will try to change my hook to see how. thanks!

Comment: You can use the same hook `admin_init` with a lower priority to ensure that your method is called later.